# My navbar after collapsing doesn't display items as list

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, toggle, navbar

I want my navbar to appear as a list after collapsing when User press toggle button but it appears in one line and not as a list

[This is how the navbar looks i dont want it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydV6m.png)

[This is how i want it to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ITy8.png)

```
 <!-- Navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-md bg-dark">

      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><i class="fas fa-child text-warning fa-2x"></i></a>
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler bg-light" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target ="#nav">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-between" id="nav">
      <ul class="navbar nav">
        <li class = "nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-light font-weight-bold text-uppercase px-3" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class = "nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-light font-weight-bold text-uppercase px-3" href="#">Skills</a>
        </li>
        <li class = "nav-item dropdown" data-toggle = "dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link text-light font-weight-bold text-uppercase px-3 dropdown-toggle" href="#">Projects</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Project 1</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Project 2</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Project 3</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Project 4</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class = "nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-light font-weight-bold text-uppercase px-3" href="#">Team</a>
        </li>
        <li class = "nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-light font-weight-bold text-uppercase px-3" href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
        <form class="form-inline">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Search" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn">
              <i class="fas fa-search text-muted "></i>
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
</div>
    </nav>

<!-- End of navbar -->
```

Comment: You need to add CSS also.

Comment: ul.navbar.nav {
    flex-direction: column;
    display: flex;
} or just display:block; on small screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about this?

```
<!-- Navbar -->
<nav class="navbar bg-dark navbar-dark">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data- 
 toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar" aria- 
 expanded="true">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse show" 
id="collapsibleNavbar" style="">
<ul class="navbar-nav">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0)">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0)">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0)">Link</a>
  </li>    

<li>
<form class="form-inline">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Search" 
class="form-control">
      </div>
</li>
</ul>
 </div>  
</nav>

<!-- End of navbar -->
```